# $f= e^{-x}$ is not a contraction but $f^2$ is

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $f(x)=e^{-x}$

$a)$ Show that f is not a contraction

$b)$ Show that $f^2$ given by $f(x):=e^{-e^{-x}}$ is a contraction

### My attempt

$f$ is a contraction if we can find a $c<1$ such that $$|f(x)-f(y)|<c|x-y|$$

$a)$ Let $|f(x)-f(y)|=|e^{-x}-e^{-y}|$

If $x=0$ and $y=-3$ then

$$|e^0-e^{-(-3)}|>|0-(-3)|$$

Which is a counter-example

$b)$ Not sure what to do here...

Comment: Hint: for *(b)*, examine the derivative of $e^{e^{-x}}$.

Comment: if i typed it correctly on wolfram alpha its some complicated derivative with a log involved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint for Part B**:

If we rearrange that thing, we'll arrive at $\displaystyle \frac{| f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|} < c$.  How large can the left hand side get?  According to the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), the left hand side is bounded by the absolute value of the largest possible evaluation of the function's derivative, and $\displaystyle \frac{\text{d}f^2}{\text{d}x} = e^{-e^{-x}-x}$.  Convincing yourself that this derivative attains its maximum at $x=0$ is most of the way to being done: from this, you'll notice that the derivative evaluated at zero gives a suitable $c$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. That is pretty tricky. What I understood from your answer is that $\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \leq \max|f'(c)|$ since it is bounded by the largest possible evaluation of the function's derivative. The goal is to find a $c$ value that is less than $1$ to prove that it is a contraction.

Comment: That's correct.  Working with the derivative is admittedly kind of a pain. 
 I'd approach it like this: Suppose we plug $x=0$ into the derivative.  Now let's consider two cases: pushing $x$ in the negative direction, and pushing $x$ in the positive direction. For the former, take advantage of the fact that $e^x > x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  For the latter, notice that we're working with $e^{-(e^{-x} + x)}$, and $e^{-x} + x \geq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (with a minimum at zero).  In either case, you'll find that moving away from zero makes $e$'s negative exponent *even more negative*.

Comment: So are you saying that the $c$ value we found is $0$?

Comment: To see that the first derivative has its maximum at 0, you can also just look at the second derivative, whose sign is easy to read off.

Comment: @combostudent, the $c$ value will be $\displaystyle \frac{df^2}{dx}$ evaluated at zero, namely $1/e$.